# how does ScalarDb support pagination

Tags: scalardb

I am using ScalarDB which provides ACID functionality on Cassandra. Does ScalarDB support pagination?

If a partition has say 100 records, can I query 10 records at a time with each query starting from where the previous one left?

Answer (score 1):

No, Scalar DB doesn't support pagination.
It has to be done in an application side.